# Java - Making a chatserver for multiple clients - how many threads do i need?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, server, chat

So I've been given a school exercise, where I am to make a chatserver in java. I've done it in TCP, but I could just aswell have done it in UDP.

I'm starting to do some thread implementations, but now I'm not really sure how I should approach it, and how many threads to make.
So fare, this is my approach:

Server needs 1 thread for running, 1 thread for receiving messages, and 1 thread to send messages. Furthermore, I've made a thread for each Client connected, which the server puts in a ClientThread[], which is then used for messaging each client. This comes to a total of 13 threads ( 10 clients max )

Furthermore, I guess each local client needs a local thread, for sending and receiving messages aswell.

Is this the right approach here? Will it be problematic to have a server running 13 threads?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close it as "opinion based", but your approach seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks solid, but you don't really want to handle an array of so much client threads. You should use [Threadpools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

You store in memory a list of already initialized threads, you only open them at startup and close them at shutdown. every time a client/server needs to send a message, you will use a thread, then return it to the pool (instead of closing it). you can also configure a pool to grow on demand

Comment: Thanks :) I'm looking into this a bit now, it seems like a really good option

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, but the point of having a thread-per-client in the server process is that each thread _waits_ for incoming messages from its client.  You can't return that to a pool until the client closes the connection.  The alternative would be to have _one_ thread that uses a `java.nio.channels.Selector` to wait for incoming messages from any client, and which handles each message by assigning a task to a pool thread.  That would be more scalable than the thread-per-client architecture, but probably harder to implement/understand.

Comment: Correct, but it's just homework. just by suggesting threadpools i'm overkilling the problem, luckily Java has them out of the box. If the question was for the C language, I wouldn't have suggested it